# WYSIWYG web form editor / designer through web page ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008, asp.net-ajax

My Client wants me to develop a system where a user can design forms through a web page, kind of WYSIWYG form editor, where we'll have a toolbox to select among the available set draggable html controls and will be placed on a canvas of N X M matrix (table or grid).

A control when placed inside a cell should snap to the left boundary. There will a mechanism to persist the position of the controls to database, like which control is placed in which row and column.

Here, I am looking for some solution or ideas or some non restrictive open source framework to achieve the UI functionality i.e, dragging the html controls to the canvas and should be able to pick the positions on saving to the database. Something similar to http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html but instead of widgets we'll have html controls.

The technologies used in my project are ASP.NET 3.5, VS 2008, jQuery, Sql Server 2008

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and warm regards.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What is your question?

Comment: @Dutchie432 I need some ideas on how to achieve the UI functionality where an end user should be able to design html form on the fly through drag drop of html controls. And all this needs to be done through a web page.

Comment: Do you mean something like asp .net WebParts? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Edward: similar to the WebParts, but instead of widgets the end user should be able to place form elements like textbox, dropdownlist, radiobuttons etc. on page, and the entire thing needs to persist in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for offering support. Using jQuery UI, I have implemented it from scratch.